# NodeJS/React/Firestore - Storing Query results within State

Tags: node.js, reactjs, google-cloud-firestore

```
function collectres () {
  var store ='';
  var docRef = db.collection("cities").doc("SF");
  docRef.get()
    .then(function (doc) {
      if (doc.exists) {
        console.log("Document data:", doc.data());
        store = doc.data();// when referenced outside, it doesnt hold anything.
      } else {
        // doc.data() will be undefined in this case
        console.log("No such document!");
      }
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log("Error getting document:", error);
    });
  return store; // returns nothing and seems to not notice the assignment.
}
```

I initially completed a simple get and wanted to store it in a variable. I then added a callback function in a index.js file, so i could call this method and then do more operations on the results.
My callback looked like this:

```
user.CollectRes(function(store){
      console.log(store.name);
      name =store.name;
      console.log(name);
     // this.setState({name:store.name});
    });
    console.log(name); // want to be able to reference this outside the callback function. So i can display it on the page.
```

I was wondering how would i be able to take the query results and store it in the state so i can reference it anywhere in the index.js file.

Comment: `doc.data()` is asynchronous, so you need to `await` it or use a `.then()`

Answer (score 0):

Adding an await statement to your code will ensure that the store call finishes before the function returns store which is undefined until the response comes back.

```
async function collectres () {
      var store ='';
      var docRef = db.collection("cities").doc("SF");
      docRef.get()
        .then(function (doc) {
          if (doc.exists) {
            console.log("Document data:", doc.data());
            store = await doc.data();// when referenced outside, it doesnt hold anything.
          } else {
            // doc.data() will be undefined in this case
            console.log("No such document!");
          }
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
          console.log("Error getting document:", error);
        });
      return store; // returns nothing and seems to not notice the assignment.
    }
```

Comment: Parsing error: Can not use keyword 'await' outside an async function. I keep getting this error.

Comment: Lool, Sorry about that, Now it just returns a promise but no value.Im sorry for asking so many questions.

Comment: you'll need to await your call to collectres :)  so... await collectres().then((data) => console.log(data))

Comment: I've done that and now it just shows a blank space when i log it in developer tools.